# how to send an array of string to Firebase cloud function?

Tags: google-app-engine, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I have an cron job running in Appengine; it gets all items from the DB then doing some analysis on it then the outcome of this analysis (some selected items)  need to be inserted into Firebase Realtime Database nodes based on this result

what Im doing now is Im accessing Firebase Rest API to insert them one by one and it really takes too much time, and I cant use Firebase SDK since im using automatic scaling, one of the options is the cloud function so that i can just send an array of items data then the function will insert them but I have some concerns:

1- the items count may easily reach 10k how can i send to cloud function this huge payload?

2- any sample code of how can i read the array parameter in cloud function Im very new in cloud function and I tried to google it but so far no clear result

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe it would help if you also say which programming language you are using

Comment: Im using Java in appengine, and I use javascript in cloud function

Comment: Are you sure you're not able to use the firebase admin SDK with GAE auto scaling?  You might be looking at old documentation.

Comment: yes im sure, cause it needs basic/manual scaling, I tried it yesterday once again and it fails cause of that